# How To Remove Extra Horizontal Line In Matplotlib Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting data from a .txt file using Matplotlib and although the plot looks as expected there is an odd horizontal line through the plot. This occurs across three different .txt data files I've tried. I plotted the data in Mathematica to ensure that it is not an artifact of the data. I am trying to remove the line from my data.

I've tried the accessing some of the Matplotlib methods like lines.remove() with no luck. Below is the code I'm executing and the resulting plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

neon = np.loadtxt("data/neon.txt")
neon_plot = plt.plot(neon)
plt.grid()
```

[This is an example of the horizontal line going through my plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q98Qe.jpg)

Comment: The blue line are your x data plotted on a y scale. Most probably you will want to plot `plt.plot(neon[:,0], neon[:,1])` instead. Or more generally, always plot `plt.plot(x,y)` such that it is easier to grasp that `plt.plot(y)` is missing something.

Comment: You're absolutely right I'm an idiot. This fixed it. Thank you.